# Unity 3D Package Manager Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started with a Unity Personal Account
and everything went great till I want to start a new project. This is the first project I want to open. The problem is, it says that it wants to connect to the server but after 30 seconds it shows me this error message:

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having this issue when updated from patch version to v2017.2.0f3. Roll back to [previous version](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) of Unity 3D solved the problem temporary. Waiting for the next version.

Answer (score 0):

My Unity version was also crashing with the Package Manager while "resolving packages". Running Unity as administrator fixed all my problems.